# how to send email to multiple users in php mailer

Tags: phpmailer

I want to send email to two users when the count is not zero. When I am making
  `$semail = $row_seller['seller_email'];` its working but when I make it
`$semail = $row_seller['seller_email'].",example@gmail.com";` its not, I want to send it to both. How can i do it.

```
<?php

$query1 = "select * from `seller` where seller_pincode = $pincode";
$run_query1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
$count_seller = mysqli_num_rows($run_query1);

if ($count_seller == 0)
{
    $semail = "example@gmail.com";
    $sname = $saddress = $spincode = $scity = $sstate = $sphone = $sgst = $span = "Not Available";
}
else
{
    while ($row_seller = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query1))
    {
        $semail = $row_seller['seller_email'] . ",example@gmail.com";
    }
}

$email = $semail;
$subject = "Order Details";
$message = 'You got a new Order!!! ";

require_once('mailer / class . phpmailer . php);

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use addAddress method or addCC for add copy, like so

```
$mail->addAddress('mail@domain.com', 'NAME'); //add address
$mail->addCC('mail@domain.com', 'NAME'); / add copy
```

[Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)